Error in chol.default(derivs_for_se$H) : the leading minor of order 373 is not positive definite
I have a simple script in R and I'm trying to run a bi-variate fixed effect ordered probit model using mvord:
# Load the data
safety_comfort_full <- read.csv("/Users/..../Data/roundabout_safety_comfort_responses.csv")

# Inspect the structure and summary of the data
str(safety_comfort_full)
summary(safety_comfort_full)

# Calculate z-scores and create new variables
safety_comfort_full <- safety_comfort_full %>%
  mutate(
    Violations = round(rowMeans(scale(select(., Q1_1, Q1_2, Q1_3)))),
    Errors = round(rowMeans(scale(select(., Q1_4, Q1_5, Q1_6, Q1_7, Q1_8, Q1_9)))),
    Positive_behavior = round(rowMeans(scale(select(., Q1_10, Q1_11, Q1_12))))
  )

# Convert `ResponseId` to a factor
safety_comfort_full$ResponseId <- as.factor(safety_comfort_full$ResponseId)

# Make sure 'Comfort' and 'Safety' are ordered factors
safety_comfort_full$Comfort <- as.ordered(safety_comfort_full$Comfort)
safety_comfort_full$Safety <- as.ordered(safety_comfort_full$Safety)


# Fit the multivariate ordinal regression model with fixed effects
fit <- mvord(
  formula = MMO2(Safety,Comfort) ~   Separation_from_Vehicle_Lane + Bike_Yielding_Priority +     Art_Ads_in_Center + Uni_Directional + Bike_Volumes + Facility_Style + X4_Legged 
  + Q23_2 + Q3 + Q4 + Q6 + Q32 + Q33 + Q5 + Q23_1 + Q23_3 + Q23_4 + Q23_5 + 
  Q23_6 + Q23_7 + Q23_8 + Violations + Errors + Positive_behavior + Roundabout_Number + ResponseId,  
  data = safety_comfort_full,
  error.structure = cor_general(~ 1),
  link = mvprobit(),
  threshold.constraints = NULL,
  control = mvord.control()
)

summary(fit)

However I receive an error when running the model:
Error in chol.default(derivs_for_se$H) :    the leading minor of order 373 is not positive definite
I found this question from a couple of years ago but they were using a different library and I'm not sure how to solve it using the mvord library.
I've tried to implement regularizing means for the independent variables but it doesn't seem to work.

It looks like your model is not of full rank.  But it's complex and we don't have access to your data.  Try starting with a model with only one term.  Add terms one by one until the error recurs.  Then look for linear dependencies between that term and any others.

@Limey thanks for the tip. I realized that it is related to the ResponseId variable which repeats itself 8 rows before changing. It is my respondent ID since  I have a panel data set. I was trying to incorporate it directly into my regression equation since I was going with a fixed effects approach. For some reason that doesn't work though as the model converges but it gets an error when calculating the Hessian matrix.
